# "Missing <soap-env:Header> in <soap-env:Envelope>" - Sabre Webservice Consumer in Mule 4

Tags: web-services, soap, dataweave, sabre, mulesoft

Attempting to call Sabre web service but getting the above SOAP error. Clearly the header is not missing. Stumped at this point.

Incoming params are passed into Transform Message processor and payload is converted to XML and passed into Web Service Consumer to make external call. The Consumer config uses the WSDL provided by Sabre.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Dataweave code in Transform processor:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
ns eb http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader
ns wsse http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext
---
{
    soapenv#Envelope: {
        soapenv#Header: 
            eb#MessageHeader: {
                eb#From: {
                    eb#PartyId: {}
                },
                eb#To: {
                    eb#PartyId: {}
                },
                eb#CPAId: "XX",
                eb#ConversationId: vars.responseVars.conversationId,
                eb#Service: "DisplayInventoryRecordLLSRQ",
                eb#Action: "DisplayInventoryRecordLLSRQ",
                eb#MessageData: {
                    eb#MessageId: {},
                    eb#Timestamp: {},
                    eb#TimeToLive: {}
            },
            wsse#Security: {
                wsse#BinarySecurityToken: vars.responseVars.securityToken
            }
        },
        soapenv#Body: {
            DisplayInventoryRecordRQ: {
                POS: {
                    Source: {
                        PseudoCityCode: vars.requestVars.origin
                },
                FlightNumber: vars.requestVars.flightNumber,
                DepartureDate: vars.requestVars.departureDate,
                DepartureAirport: {
                    LocationCode: "ALL"
                },
                ArrivalAirport: {
                    LocationCode: vars.requestVars.destination, 
                    CodeContext: "IATA"
                    }   
                }           
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

XML passed to Consumer:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId/>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId/>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>XX</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>### Masked ###</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>DisplayInventoryRecordLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>DisplayInventoryRecordLLSRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId/>
                <eb:Timestamp/>
                <eb:TimeToLive/>
            </eb:MessageData>
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>### Masked ###</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            </wsse:Security>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <DisplayInventoryRecordRQ>
            <POS>
                <Source>
                    <PseudoCityCode>XXX</PseudoCityCode>
                </Source>
                <FlightNumber>###</FlightNumber>
                <DepartureDate>2020-03-05</DepartureDate>
                <DepartureAirport>
                    <LocationCode>ALL</LocationCode>
                </DepartureAirport>
                <ArrivalAirport>
                    <LocationCode>XXX</LocationCode>
                    <CodeContext>IATA</CodeContext>
                </ArrivalAirport>
            </POS>
        </DisplayInventoryRecordRQ>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR 2020-03-05 13:01:25,188 [[MuleRuntime].io.10: [proc-ix-action-server-app].main-flow.BLOCKING @72b2e7e6] [event: 1594fcb1-5f1c-11ea-b89c-8c04ba8b4cea] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorContinueHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Missing <soap-env:Header> in <soap-env:Envelope>.
Error type            : WSC:SOAP_FAULT
Element               : get-inventory-subflow/processors/0/processors/1 @ proc-ix-action-server-app:main.xml:133 (Consume)
Element XML           : <wsc:consume operation="DisplayInventoryRecordRQ" doc:name="Consume" doc:id="fbeaeba3-f04c-4d40-bf87-bd63c1a8ac34" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config"></wsc:consume>
```

Working Postman call for comparison:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId />
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId />
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>XX</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>### Masked ###</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service>DisplayInventoryRecordLLSRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>DisplayInventoryRecordLLSRQ</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId />
        <eb:Timestamp />
        <eb:TimeToLive />
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">### Masked ###</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <DisplayInventoryRecordRQ TimeStamp="2010-11-30T15:30:00-06:00" Version="1.2.1" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="XXX"/>
        </POS>
        <FlightNumber>##</FlightNumber>
        <DepartureDate>2020-03-05</DepartureDate>
        <DepartureAirport LocationCode="XXX"/>
        <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="XXX" CodeContext="IATA"/>
    </DisplayInventoryRecordRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is DisplayInventoryRecordPortType and DisplayInventoryRecordService ?  Are those just string literals or are you trying to access a variable or value from a properties file?

Comment: Those are pulled in from the wsdl file when it's loaded into the config

Comment: Have you tried pasting the output of that dataweave into postman?  What happens?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header/>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unable to internalize message</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <StackTrace>javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to internalize message</StackTrace>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>`

Comment: On the request in Mule your wsse:Security tag is inside the eb:MessageHeader.  In your Postman request you have it outside of your eb:MessageHeader.  Could that be causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the body contents only as the payload, not the soap elements. Those are added by the Web Service Consumer.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried eliminating the Envelope, Header, and Body tags but Mule still wants some kind of root tag because it throws a "Trying to output second root" error on whichever tag is first.

Comment: The body doesn't has a root tag? I'll try to search for some example.